# Visio VBA drawing line with coordinates as meters

Tags: vba, visio

I am working in Visio with VBA. Is there a way to change the starting point from page corner to coordinates of x,y?

When I create a macro it automatically takes the starting point as a page corner and it changes when the page shape changes as well. I want to draw a line as x,y coordinates like it shows in the image.

Coordinates as it shows in Visio

[image]

I tried to find a way like in excel to change coordinates like in the code that follows,

```vb
With Range("C5")
   BeginX = .Left
   BeginY = .Top + .Height / 2
 End With`
```

Of course this code only works in cell environment but I wondered if there was a way to change it to a Visio environment that would take x,y coordinates as basis instead of a cell.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question vs the title. Do you want to change the origin of the coordinate system or is there a unit conversion involved as well?

Comment: Sorry for replying late and for the confusing explanation. I only want the change the origin of coordinate system. I dont need to do unit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This code originally posted at [Lessons/Draw lines from Excel tables](https://github.com/Obsidian-pb/VisioLessons/blob/master/Lessons/Draw%20lines%20from%20Excel%20tables/ThisDocument.cls).

> ```
> Public Sub DrawFromEcel() 
> Dim exApp As Excel.Application Dim i As
> Integer Dim exSheet As Excel.Worksheet
>     Set exApp = New Excel.Application
>     exApp.Visible = False
>
>     exApp.Workbooks.Open ("c:\Coord.xls")
>     Set exSheet = exApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
>     
>     i = 2
>     Do While exSheet.Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
>         Application.ActivePage.DrawLine exSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, exSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, _
>                                         exSheet.Range("C" & i).Value, exSheet.Range("D" & i).Value
>         
>         i = i + 1
>         
>     Loop
>     
>     exApp.Quit 
> End Sub
> ```

In this example, values are given in **inches**. Inches is the default Visio unit of measure!
If you have values stored in meters in your table, you will need to divide these values by `25.4` to convert them to inches…

```
Application.ActivePage.DrawLine exSheet.Range("A" & i).Value/25.4, exSheet.Range("B" & i).Value/25.4, _
                                         exSheet.Range("C" & i).Value/25.4, exSheet.Range("D" & i).Value/25.4
```

Comment: Generally when you post something that is 100% someone else's work, you make it a Community Wiki post.

Comment: I broke the Code of Conduct ? One of the lines had to be changed, because the topiс-starter wanted to store values in meters…

Comment: Code that is copied from somewhere else must be placed in block quotes because you are quoting someone else's content. Otherwise you risk your post being deleted for plagiarism. Likewise if your entire post is "I found this solution that someone else created", it's ethically recommended to convert your post to Community Wiki to ensure you are not trying to gain reputation or some other benefit off the back of someone else's work.

Comment: I don't know how convert post to Community wiki?

Comment: Click edit, and then on the bottom right below the editor field there is a checkbox for it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMksM.png

Comment: Users very often don't give reputations for correct answers, or even just say "thank you" for helping. Would it be better for me to mark all my answers as Community Wiki?

Comment: A Community Wiki designation indicates that a post is primarily a _collaborative effort_. This means it's appropriate for any post you expect or want to be heavily edited by others over the years, or for any post where you are just re-sharing existing content and not a significant contributor of your own words/solution. It's not particularly appropriate for other answers. It's also not reversible without moderator assistance, so don't go marking all your answers as CW or you may regret it later.

Comment: Basically, no matter what I do on StackOverFlow I will still regret it? )